# Stack Overflow error from recursive directory traversal

Tags: java, android, recursion, directory, stack-overflow

When I'm running this method I immediately get a stack overflow exception so obviously the method keeps recursively calling itself however I'm not sure why. For reference the file structure I'm testing it with is a load of folders and in those folders are files, no other folders

```
    public void files(File[] f)
    {
    if(f == null){
        return;
    }
    else
    {   
    for(int i = 0; i < f.length; i++)
    {
        if(f[i].isFile() && (f[i].getName().contains(".mp3") || f[i].getName().contains(".m4a"))) //iterate through files and check if each file matches the required criteria 
        {
                String fullname = f[i].getName();
                Log.v("full name", fullname);
                String name = null;
                if(fullname.contains(".mp3"))
                {
                name = fullname.substring(0, fullname.lastIndexOf(".mp3"));
                }
                else if(fullname.contains(".m4a"))                                  //Removing file extensions of music file so they can be displayed using an appropriate name
                {
                    name = fullname.substring(0, fullname.lastIndexOf(".m4a"));
                }
                list.add(name);
                mp3.add(f[i]);
                Log.v("added", name);
        }
        if(f[i].isDirectory())
        {
            File inner[] = files[i].listFiles();
            files(inner);
        }

    }
    }

   }
```

Comment: First thing I'd do is add more logging. Next thing I'd do is change the recursive call to accept *one* file - just because that's simpler to deal with.

Comment: Tried it using 4 folders and quite a few files and that worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe some of the files are "." and ".." which means , i think, the current folder and back one folder.

So in your isDirectory() part of the if check  also check if f[i]!="." and f[i]!=".."

```
if(f[i].isDirectory() and f[i]!="." and f[i]!="..")
    {
        File inner[] = files[i].listFiles();
        files(inner);
    }
```

EDIT:

As @Jon said, try to add more debug to it and see where it breaks exactly.

LATER EDIT:

For future readers, the problem was here:

```
    //File inner[] = files[i].listFiles();
    File inner[] = f[i].listFiles();
```

Comment: This was my first thought to, wrote it and then deleted it, because the javadocs of listFiles explicitly say that . and .. are not returned. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles()

Comment: i just noticed this, who is files[i] , shouldn't it be f[i]?

Comment: yep Radu you got it, just a dumb mistake on my part. +1 for why you shouldn't copy and past a load of code

Answer (score 0):

So super dumb mistake on my part, when copying the code from a previous non recursive implementation I forgot to change files to f in

```
if(f[i].isDirectory())
        {
            File inner[] = files[i].listFiles();
            files(inner);
        }
```